# ubuntu python script use PyAutoGui to press some buttons not run when make the focus on the sublime text editor

Tags: python, pyautogui

I wrote this script in python

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(.1)
pyautogui.keyDown("ctrl")
pyautogui.press("a")
pyautogui.keyUp("ctrl")
pyautogui.press("c")
pyautogui.press("p")
pyautogui.press("p")
pyautogui.press("t")
pyautogui.press("enter")

pyautogui.keyDown("ctrl")
pyautogui.keyDown("shift")
pyautogui.press(",")
pyautogui.keyUp("ctrl")
pyautogui.keyUp("shift")
pyautogui.press("tab")
```

And I created a shortcut in ubuntu to run it. `python3 Scripts/cpp.py`

The script works correctly when I make focus on any text element (on the browser for example). But when I make focus on the sublime text or any other text editor It does not work.

What is the reason for this issue?

*(This script makes sense and do something useful for me)*

Comment: Uh, that the keypresses don't have the intended meaning in the scope where you are focused?

Comment: @tripleee It doesn't work in sublime text or any other text editor I doesn't even make any change there. I tried to run it in any text element on the browser for example and I found it works there. But not in the desired place (I.e. the sublime text editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re running your program as administrator, pyautogui won’t be able to interact with it.  This can catch people out pretty easily because you can set certain programs to always run as administrator, so it won’t be the first thing you think of.  This is the case for Windows anyway.

On Ubuntu, from your experience, it seems like it is actually important to run it as an admin.  So I guess in general keep the privileges in mind when you have programs interacting with other programs.

Also, your script can be cleaned up a bit.

```
# Probably a good idea to have a bit of a slightly longer sleep.
time.sleep(0.3)
#pyautogui.keyDown("ctrl")
#pyautogui.press("a")
#pyautogui.keyUp("ctrl")
# Is equivalent to
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "a")

# The next block looks like you're writing text.  So write some text.
#pyautogui.press("c")
#pyautogui.press("p")
#pyautogui.press("p") 
#pyautogui.press("t")
pyautogui.write("cppt")
pyautogui.press("enter")

#pyautogui.keyDown("ctrl")
#pyautogui.keyDown("shift")
#pyautogui.press(",")
#pyautogui.keyUp("ctrl")
#pyautogui.keyUp("shift")
# Again, use a hotkey here.
pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "shift", ",")
pyautogui.press("tab")
```

Comment: This is for sure a much better code but the issue is not solved. The code script run in any text field but not in the desired sublime text.

Comment: Yep.  I can’t reproduce your issue so something else strange is going on. The only similar issue I can recall is running applications in administrator mode on Windows makes pyautogui unable to interact with them.  But you’ve stated it’s on Ubuntu, so it’s not that.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't think of that! It worked once I ran the text editors in administrator mode. Thanks a lot. Please add this to your answer.

Comment: Oh really? That carries over to Ubuntu?  Interesting.  Will add it to the answer.